# How to print selected text from JSON file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and have undertaken my first project to automate something for my role (I'm in the network space, so forgive me if this is terrible!).

I'm required to to download a .json file from the below link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519

My script goes through and retrieves the manual download link.

The reason I'm getting the URL in this way, is that the download link changes every fortnight when MS update the file.

My preference is to extract the "addressPrefixes" contents from the names of "AzureCloud.australiacentral", "AzureCloud.australiacentral2", "AzureCloud.australiaeast", "AzureCloud.australiasoutheast".

I'm then wanting to strip out characters of " & ','.

Each of the subnet ranges should then reside on a new line and be placed in a text file.

If I perform the below, I'm able to get the output that I am wanting.

Am I correct in thinking that I can use a for loop to achieve this? If so, would it be better to use a Python dictionary as opposed to using JSON formatted output?

```
# Script to check Azure IPs   
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Import Modules for script

import requests
import re
import json
import urllib.request

search = 'https://download.*?\.json'
ms_dl_centre = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519"
requests_get = requests.get(ms_dl_centre)
json_url_search = re.search(search, requests_get.text)
  
json_file = json_url_search.group(0)

with urllib.request.urlopen(json_file) as url:
        contents = json.loads(url.read().decode())
 
print(json.dumps(contents['values'][1]['properties']['addressPrefixes'], indent = 0)) #use this to print contents from json entry 1
```

Comment: You can use a ```for-loop``` to iterate over the JSON file and extract your data. And what do you mean by *use a Python dictionary* ? You want to convert JSON to dictionary and then read from the dictionary ?

Comment: Sweet, thanks for confirming that. Sorry, my terminology with this may not be right. My understanding is that this would be better converted from a JSON object to Python Dictionary? Or, is this completely way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that using re to parse HTML is a good idea. BeautifulSoup is more suited to the task. Upon inspection of the HTML response I note that there's a span element of class file-link-view1 that seems to uniquely identify the URL to the JSON download. Assuming that to be a robust approach (i.e. Microsoft don't change the way the download URL is presented) then this is how I'd do it:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
namelist = ["AzureCloud.australiacentral", "AzureCloud.australiacentral2",
            "AzureCloud.australiaeast", "AzureCloud.australiasoutheast"]
baseurl = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519'
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(baseurl)
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    downloadurl = soup.find('span', class_='file-link-view1').find('a')['href']
    response = session.get(downloadurl)
    response.raise_for_status()
    json = response.json()
    for n in json['values']:
        if n['name'] in namelist:
            print(n['name'])
            for ap in n['properties']['addressPrefixes']:
                print(ap)
```

Comment: Looks great, I'll give this a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: That worked a treat! If I want to incorporate some error handling to this script based on the URL not being available, so it doesn't write this out to a file, would I incorporate try/except into this? The purpose of this is to write the IPs to a file, which is referenced by a firewall. The firewall then uses them as objects in a security policy. If the script fails for what ever reason, the goal is to not have an empty file referenced. Happy for you to guide me on the right path to learn how to do this, as opposed to you writing this for me.

Comment: response.raise_for_status() will raise an exception if the HTTP response is not 200. You can wrap that in a try/except/finally

Comment: Sweet as, that's what I was thinking. Thank you for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @BrodieFrankfurt Instead of writing your own answer based on this, you should accept this answer via the check on the left.  You can always do that on your own questions even if you don't have the rep to upvote.

Comment: @mark-tolonen, I see, thanks for pointing that out. I've now marked it as the answer. In terms of my follow up response with my additions. Is this the right etiquette to leave this? Or, should I amend my original post with my new script?

Comment: @BrodieFrankfurt Don't edit the question with an answer.  If your own answer adds information that clarifies the original question, that's fine, but you are probably the only one that cares about the additional cleanup of the code.

Answer (score 0):

@andyknight, thanks for your direction. I'd up vote you but as I'm a noob, it doesn't permit from doing so.

I've taken the basis of your python script and added in some additional components.

I removed the print statement for the region name in the .txt file, as this is file is referenced by a firewall, which is looking for IP addresses.

I've added in Try/Except/Else for portion of the script, to identify if there is ever an error with reaching the URL, or other unspecified error. I've leveraged logging to send an email based on the status of the script. If an exception is thrown I get an email with traceback information, otherwise I receive an email advising the script was successful.

This writes out the specific prefixes for AU regions into a .txt file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
import requests
import logging
import logging.handlers
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

smtp_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=("sanitised.smtp[.]xyz", 25),
                                            fromaddr="UpdateIPs@sanitised[.]xyz", 
                                            toaddrs="FriendlyAdmin@sanitised[.]xyz",
                                            subject=u"Check Azure IP Script completion status.")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(smtp_handler)

namelist = ["AzureCloud.australiacentral", "AzureCloud.australiacentral2",
            "AzureCloud.australiaeast", "AzureCloud.australiasoutheast"]
baseurl = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56519'
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(baseurl)
try:
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    downloadurl = soup.find('span', class_='file-link-view1').find('a')['href']
    response = session.get(downloadurl)
    response.raise_for_status()
    json = response.json()
    for n in json['values']:
        if n['name'] in namelist:
            for ap in n['properties']['addressPrefixes']:
                with open('Check_Azure_IPs.txt', 'a') as file:
                    file.write(ap + "\n")
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    logger.exception(
        "URL is no longer valid, please check the URL that's defined in this script with MS, as this may have changed.\n\n")
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception("Unknown error has occured, please review script")
else:
    logger.info("Script has run successfully! Azure IPs have been updated.")
```

Please let me know if you think there is a better way to handle this, otherwise this is marked as answered. I appreciate your help greatly!

Comment: I see a number of issues. If you want to initiate a Chat, I'm happy to do that

Comment: @DarkKnight Cool, thanks for taking the time to reply. 

Where do we start? What could I do to improve this with my additions? :)

Comment: The only issue I see is the 'dangling' open file handle. Better to use 'with'

Comment: @DarkKnight, cool, I've amended this. Thanks for being patient! This is my first crack at python so appreciate it.